# MS14-066 Vulnerability (Windows Server 2012 R2) Nessus Scan

Tags: nessus

I've been trying relentlessly looking for the correct update for the MS14-066 critical (Vulnerability in Schannel) update and every time I download a different patch/version to the server, it says "it's not applicable with this computer. "  I have downloaded more than 10 different versions of this update and all of them keeps saying the same error message.  I was wondering has anyone ever heard of this error before? I've tried researching but all forums seem to not have a legitimate fix and sends me to the same Windows download page that I previously downloaded the files.  If anyone could possibly point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @C Hill - Did the MS patch below (for Vulnerability in Schannel) meet your needs?

Answer (score 0):

[This MS page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/ms15-031.aspx) points [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46268) for the update to patch for "Vulnerability in Schannel" in Windows Server 2012 R2. Different announcement number, but it appears to be the security patch that applies to your build.